# How can I save several separate text with AutoHotKey?

Tags: script, autohotkey

I don't know if this will be possible at all but here is an example for a better illustration.

Let's say we got a little list of words:

-house

-computer

-clothes

-human

Let's say we can select house by using ctrl + a. Now if we want to select next word, we press tab button, and then again ctrl + a..

I want that every word is saved somewhere, so when I press button f1, then house will be pasted. When I press f2, computer will be pasted, etc.

When I reached a specific amount of words, I want that we empty the "cache" or whatever it might be called :p

Is that possible at all with autohotkey? I got some basic knowledge but this is a bit more adventurous imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
; Create an object (array) to save the selected word (value) 
; each time you press your key (combination): 

MyArray := []
Index := 0
MaxIndex = 12       ; specific amount of words


; select next word and press your key (e.g. esc) to save the selected word in the array:

esc::
ClipSaved := ClipboardAll  ; save the entire clipboard to the variable ClipSaved
clipboard := "" ; empty clipboard
Send, ^c        ; copy the selected word
ClipWait 1      ; wait for the clipboard to contain data
If !ErrorLevel  ; If NOT ErrorLevel clipwait found data on the clipboard
{
    Index++     ; checks the number in the variable "Index" and increases it by 1, each time you press esc.
    if (Index = MaxIndex+1) ; when the specific amount of words is exceeded
    {
        Index := 1      ; set this variable to 1
        MyArray := []   ; recreate the object (empty the array)
    }
    MyArray.Insert(Index, clipboard)    
}
Sleep, 300
clipboard := ClipSaved  ; restore original clipboard
return

f1:: SendInput, % MyArray[1]
f2:: SendInput, % MyArray[2]
f12:: SendInput, % MyArray[12]
```

For better understanding the whole context, read
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#s7

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this answer, it really works as I hoped it would, perfect! :) Just one more thing. Your code empties the array when we copied a specific amount of words. Would it be possible to change your if-statement so when a specific button is pressed, that it empties the array?

Comment: Add a hotkey that does the same thing as the auto-execute section (MyArray := [] and Index := 0).